# show Widget in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon

My firefox addon uses widget and when I click on it it shows panel. Following is the code for it

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;
var tabs = require('tabs');
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: "about:blank",
  width: 200,
  height: 480,
  onHide: function(){
    panel.contentURL = data.url("loading.html")
  }
});
exports.main = function() {
    // Widget documentation: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/widget.html
    var widget = new Widget({
        id: "MobileView-widget-1",
        label: "MobileView",
        tooltip : "Start Mobile View",
        panel: panel,
        onClick: function() {
            panel.contentURL = "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#activeTab";
        },
        contentURL: data.url("mobile.png")
    });
};
```

When I click on the widget, it shows the panel above it but when the focus is out, it immediately closes and starts afresh again. How do I make sure, it wont close on loosing focus but I need to click on the widget again to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

Widget system was removed in Firefox 29, you have to now use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui

```
var { ToggleButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/toggle');
var panels = require("sdk/panel");
var self = require("sdk/self");

var button = ToggleButton({
  id: "my-button",
  label: "my button",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onChange: handleChange
});

var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
  onHide: handleHide
});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel.show({
      position: button
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  button.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

Comment: Great it worked for my new firefox but when I click on any other part of the window, panel closes. How do i prevent it from closing down unless user clicks on my icon?

Comment: look at the panel docs of addon-sdk: https://dev.mozilla.jp/addon-sdk-docs/packages/addon-kit/panel.html  it doesnt seem to have a `noauothide` feature. so you might have to get the xul element and set `noautohide` to `true`